# Hosting a stylesheet on the same server as the application using Rails Asset Pipeline

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, server, hosting, asset-pipeline

I am using a Javascript library requires a stylesheet to be hosted on the same domain as the application. Through the Rails Asset Pipeline my assets are being hosted on S3 and I want to continue doing this.  I only need one singular stylesheet to exist on the same server as the application.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to add that stylesheet in your assets directory and require/import it in your application.css/application.scss.

Comment: @Saad Yes, my assets get automatically uploaded to S3 via the asset pipeline. My problem is that I want this ONE specific vendor CSS File to be uploaded to my Rails server along with the Rails app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it's as simple as just putting the file I'd like to be hosted with my Rails app in the `public` directory and then linking to the stylesheet from there.